# installing zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am running ubuntu hardy

I installed zend framework using : sudo apt-get install zend-framework command

Why did it not install zf.sh ?
I want to be able to use the zend_tool using cli.
How do I go about getting the zf.sh command to work?

Comment: Did you try `locate zf.sh` to see if Ubuntu can find the directory that the script is in?

Answer (score 0):

Try sudo apt-get install zendframework-bin. The description for zendframework-bin is "binary scripts for zendframework". So this might be what you need to install.

Answer (score 0):

to use zf.sh you should create an alias for that

like this ..

alias zf='/home/kanishka/workspace/zend/bin/zf.sh'

after that you can use zf in command line

now this should work :- zf create project test ,